# for a user id java.mail throws 'AUTHENTICATE failed.' , but can log in through browser

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server-2007

I am using **java mail api** for reading the mails (using imap). I have **2 different mail boxes** to read.

Following is configuration used :-

```
Microsoft Exchange Server 2007

java mail  :- tried javamail-1.4 , javamail-1.5
imap.url=imapmail.somedomain.com
imap.port=143

mail.user1=user_id_doesnt_work
mail.pwd1=some_pwd

mail.user2=user_id_works
mail.pwd2=some_pwd
```

java code :-

```
private void loginInbox() throws MessagingException{

    Folder inbox = null;
    Properties mailProps =  mailProps = new Properties();

   mailProps.put("mail.store.protocol", "imapmail.somedomain.com");
   mailProps.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
   mailProps.put("mail.imap.starttls.required", "true");

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailProps);
   Store store = session.getStore();

   store.connect("imapmail.somedomain.com", 143, EMAILUSER, EMAILPWD);    //throws exception here

   inbox = store.getFolder(INBOX);
   inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

}
```

> I am able to **login to both mail boxes through browser** ,with both user
>   id and password (url = imapmail.somedomain.com )

**> Using JavaMail :-**

Using java mail 'mail.user2=user_id_works' , I am able to login to mail.

But When I use java mail 'mail.user1=user_id_doesnt_work' throws exception :

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.    at
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:723)   at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)

Could be there **any server settings** for that particular user which prevents login attempt ?
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that EMAILUSER, EMAILPWD are wrongly populated in store.connect call.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear how your properties are being used since the code you posted ignores them.  I'm assuming that's not really the code you're using.

[Change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance), as described in the list of [common mistakes in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: yes for simplicity , readability and restrictions, I do have to remove some  code.
But what I want to point out is for one user id it works and for 2nd it fails. ( able to login through browser for both) 

And I did print [user name] , [password] values to console and tried them through browser , was able to login.

So my guess is that user profile might have some restrictions .is that something possible?

Comment: Did you try the fix I suggested?  Did you read the FAQ entry explaining it?

Comment: yes  , I tried that too, Getting the same results.  thanks for inputs , now talking to sysadmin.

Comment: If you change the properties so there's only one user name and password, does it make any difference?  Does the failing user name or password contain any "unusual" characters?

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue at work today so I hope this helps some people.

Our container, Weblogic had two jars in it's path: Javamail 1.1 (I think) and javamail 1.4.1.

After switching debug on we saw that it was erroring out with `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException`. We switched to a newer version of javamail and the issue was resolved.